# Как указать путь к файлу?

Tags: java

Первый раз пытаюсь разместить файлы программы по папкам для удобной работы.
Для этого использую команду package.
Придумал название для пакета - com.pumaex
Использую в работе IntelliJIdea.
В результате java-файлы оказались в директории:
"C:\Users\Ura\IdeaProjects\Lines\src\com\pumaex"
Графические файлы для программы расположил в директорию:
"C:\Users\Ura\IdeaProjects\Lines\src\assets\images"
Подскажите, как правильно указать путь к графическому файлу в строке оператора?

```
Background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("   ???//Pole1.png    "));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно думаю, C:/Users/Ura/IdeaProjects/Lines/src/assets/images.
Можно использовать System.getProperty("user.home") и добавить к нему что нужно.

Но обычно ресурсы хранят в своей директории и доступ можно получить из приложения [просто](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Comment: Не понял. Мой проект находится в каталоге Lines.

Comment: Мой проект находится в каталоге Lines. Java-файлы в Lines\src\com\pumaex. Рядом, в своей директории, находятся ресурсы - Lines\src\assets\images. Я не могу понять как получить доступ к этой директории с ресурсами? Я попробовал ("user.home")  - почему-то не получается достучаться до файлов.

Comment: А первый вариант сработал?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался